# How to draw simple arrow between words in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, arrows

Under Beamer, how to draw a sipmle arrow between words in itemize?

I do not need to configure the size, location or any other detail settings. What I need is simply a default arrow.

I tried `\rightarrow` and `\implies` but without luck.

Comment: What kind of an arrow do you want? Do you want an arrow that looks like `\rightarrow`? Did you do `$\rightarrow$`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the arrows, you need to be in math mode.  E.g.,

```
    \begin{itemize}
    \item This $\rightarrow$ that
    \end{itemize}
```

You shouldn't need any special packages for that to work.

Answer (score 8):

Choose the one you like:

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{marvosym} % \MVRIGHTarrow
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % \shortrightarrow
\usepackage{textcomp} % \textrightarrow

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This \MVRightarrow{} that
            \item This $\shortrightarrow$ that
            \item This \textrightarrow{} that
            \item This $\rightarrow$ that
            \item This $\longrightarrow$ that
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And if you prefer the "implies" version:

[image]

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item This $\Rightarrow$ that
    \item This $\Longrightarrow$ that
    \item This $\implies$ that
\end{itemize}
```